# Monitors turn off for a second, Windows does the device disconnect and connect sound

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I have two different monitors, one's a Samsung and the other's an LG. I recently movedand had my computer mailed over. Since setting it up here, randomly both monitors will turn black and come back immediatelly, twice, with a delay of a few seconds in between. The first time this happens Windows' "device disconnected" sound is heard, the next time the "device connected" sound is heard. USBLogView doesn't show any events, Event Viewer doesn't show anything useful. It's quite baffling. Didn't have this problem ever before.

I have a GeForce GTX 460 and I'm running the 314.22 driver. I had Process Explorer running, and whenever that happened, two Intel graphics-related processes popped-up and disappeared immediatelly. The monitors however are connected to the NVidia graphics card, so that doesn't make sense. I uninstalled the Intel HD Graphics Driver, made sure to delete those EXEs, the same thing keeps happening.

It's not that the monitor goes into power-save and comes back either, because I'm using the PC at that moment.  Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a GPU "recovery", where the GPU (be it software or hardware issues) has crashed.  The intel then comming up, might be logical, when the one is gone, the other becomes active. A GPU crash though should be showing in the logs.  Q. what activity are you doing when this happens?  Because you moved, I would try re-seating the card as the first thing.  Have the computer fully disconnected from the wall (not just shut-down) and slide the card out of the slot, than back in again. Also do the same with the power wires on the back , then plug back in and hope.

Comment: The card has been reseated, because my tower got trashed on the way over and I had to move all the components to a new one. Disabling the Intel HD Graphics chipset through Device Manager has seemed (so far) to stop this issue, so I'm guessing for whatever reason Windows was trying to switch to the Intel one. If it was the NVidia card shutting down though, I should still be seeing issues, with the exception that Windows wouldn't have the Intel chip to switch to. Still baffles me.